# Problem with Arduino line follower

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, ir

I am making a line follower robot. My code is like this

```
#define motI1 10
#define motI2 6
#define motI3 5
#define motI4 3

int left=9;   // left sensor
int right=1;  // right sensor

void setup() {
  pinMode(motI1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motI2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motI3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motI4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(left, INPUT);
  pinMode(right, INPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  if(((digitalRead(left))==HIGH)&&((digitalRead(right))==HIGH)) {
    digitalWrite(motI1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motI2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motI3, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motI4, LOW);
    Serial.println("FORWARD");
    delay(1);
  } else if(((digitalRead(left))==HIGH)&&((digitalRead(right))==LOW)) {
    // turn right
    digitalWrite(motI1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motI2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(motI3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(motI4,LOW);
    Serial.println("Right turn Right Sensor LOW");
    delay(1);
  } else if(((digitalRead(left))==LOW)&&((digitalRead(right))==HIGH)) {
    // turn left
    digitalWrite(motI1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(motI2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(motI3,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motI4,LOW);
    Serial.println("Left turn Left Sensor LOW");
    delay(1);
  } else if(((digitalRead(left))==LOW)&&((digitalRead(right))==LOW)) {
    digitalWrite(motI1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(motI2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(motI3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(motI4,LOW);
    Serial.println("Stop");
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

Only pin 1 of the Arduino is working but other pins are not working for the IR sensor. But the pins for the motor are working just fine. What is the real problem?

Comment: Are you sure it's working? Pin 1 is used as Serial Tx line. Is there possibility that IR sensors requires pull up resistor?

Comment: Yes pin 1 is working. I don't think IR sensor requires pull up resistor.

Comment: Battery operated?  Disconnect the motors and measure to see if the sensor and motor control states are as you expect them when moving the sensors across the line.  Often people skip over the pitfalls of high current / low voltage problems when using batteries or even under powered wall supplies.

Comment: What kind of line-following sensor is it? If it's like the Sparkfun IR sensors, then they need to be connected to ADC pins and a digitalRead won't work on them.